# GIT: Fork git repro can't checkout branches

Tags: git, svn, github, git-checkout

I fork repo but the origin of the for has multiple branches and on my fork (web) I can see the the branches but when I try to switch branches on my computer I'm getting the following errors:

```
error: pathspec 'myBranch01' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If I check if the branch exist:

```
git branch -a |grep myBranch01
```

I get:

```
  remotes/origin/myBranch01
  remotes/upstram/myBranch01
  remotes/upstream/myBranch01
```

any of you knows why I'm getting this error?, or what I'm doing wrong?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Git will automatically create a branch for you, if you don't have one yourself but you do have a corresponding *remote-tracking branch* (note that a remote-tracking branch is not a branch!).

The problem here is not that you don't have a corresponding remote-tracking branch.  The problem is that you have *too many* corresponding remote-tracking branches.

You told Git to get on to, or create if necessary, `myBranch01`.  There are *three* possible `myBranch01` names it could use to create yours:

- `origin/myBranch01`
- `upstram/myBranch01`
- `upstream/myBranch01`

The middle one is clearly due to a typo.  But even if you delete the typo-ed remote, which takes away all those remote-tracking branches, you will still be left with *two* possible `myBranch01` sources.  Git won't know which one to use, so it will refuse to use *either one*.

The solution is to *tell* Git which one to use to create *your* branch.  Once you have created your own branch, the other two remote-tracking branch names are much less important and it won't matter that there are two of them.

You can:

```
git checkout --track origin/myBranch01
```

to make your own `myBranch01` from `origin/myBranch01`, or:

```
git checkout --track upstream/myBranch01
```

to make your own `myBranch01` from `upstream/myBranch01`.

Which one of these you *should* use is a different question entirely (and one only you can answer).

Comment: What is the difference between remotes/origin/myBranch01 and  remotes/upstream/myBranch01 ?

Comment: " git checkout --track " it would create a new branch. Correct?

Comment: For your first question, I can only see the obvious difference: one is spelled with `origin` and one is spelled with `upstream`. Presumably this is because you have one remote named `origin` and another named `upstream` (plus the typo-ed one). For your second: yes, `git checkout --track <remote-tracking-branch>` is shorthand for `git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote-tracking-branch>`, where Git computes the local branch name by taking off the obvious part from the remote-tracking branch name.

Comment: on my case I don't want to create new branch I want to use the branches are already created

Comment: If you are going to make any commits yourself, you *must* make a new branch, otherwise you will not have any branches: remote-tracking branches are not branches! If you are just using a commit, you can use a "detached HEAD" and hence not use a branch. The choice is yours.